# Multiple table join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario whereby I have 3 tables (`Table1, Table2, Table3`)

`Table1` contains data whereby each `MEMBNO` is unique

I would like to `JOIN` to `Table2` and `Table3` to display results but only have one row for each result

I tried

```
SELECT A.MEMBNO,A.FIELD1,B.FIELD1,B.FIELD2,C.FIELD1
FROM Table1 A
INNER join Table2 B ON A.MEMBNO = B.MEMBNO
INNER join Table3 C ON A.MEMBNO = C.MEMBNO
```

but I get multiple results. If the `MEMBNO` is in Table2 twice and Table3 four times, I get 8 rows returned.

Is my JOIN correct or is the only way to control this through the `WHERE` statement after the JOIN to control what is returned from Table2 and Table3 (ie: does SQL "dumb" join all the data and expect the `WHERE` statement to be the filer?)

Many thanks

Comment: Please specify your use case. The question now is too general.

Comment: because your relationship of table1 with table2 and table3 is one-many, thats why you are getting each record per each record in other table

Comment: @PareshJ using LEFT JOIN you'll still have multiple records.

Comment: Based on your business logic use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` on top of your `JOIN`.

Comment: Which matching row from the other two tables should SQL choose?  SQL returns all matching rows, unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: you can add further joining conditions in the `ON` clause too (not just in the `WHERE`).

Answer (score 2):

What you are fighting with is the different relationships between the data. Table1 is the primary key table which has your one row per MEMBNO. Table2\3 have more than one row for each MEMBNO. What you therefore need to think about is what data you actually want to see before you attempt the joins. The difference in cardinality is causing your row duplication when the joins are happening. If you want the data in Table2\3 to be squished into a single row, have a think how that might look. i.e. do you want to sum the numbers from the different rows into a total? do you want to take the maximum date? etc

Best thing to do is give some data examples from each table and give an example result. More than happy to have a go if you add that info.

Answer (score -1):

As I am concern about only MEMBNO. What if I use distinct of MEMBNO from both tables Table2 and Table3.

Check the below example:

```
create table #t1
(
F1 int,
F2 int
)

Insert into #t1 values(1, 111)

Create table #t2
(
F1 int,
F2 int
)

Insert into #t2 values(1, 111)
Insert into #t2 values(1, 222)

Create table #t3
(
F1 int,
F2 int
)

Insert into #t3 values(1, 333)
Insert into #t3 values(1, 444)


SELECT a.*
FroM #t1 a left join  (Select distinct f1 from #t2) b on a.F1 = b.f1
left join  (Select distinct f1 from #t3) c on a.F1 = c.f1
```

Where #t1, #t2, #t3 are table1, table2, table3 respecively
AND F1 is your MEMBNO in all the tables.

Comment: Why would you join with two tables with just a column that is the primary key of the first? I mean, you are selecting data just from the first table. This is equal to `SELECT * FROM #t1`.

Answer (score -5):

You get multiple results because of using inner join. 
You should use left or right join.

Comment: should be comment, not answer?

Comment: With LEFT or RIGHT join you'll still get multiple rows.

Comment: incorrect answer. The cardinality\relationships are the cause.